# Leaflet JS - Country Boundaries

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet JS to create a map. Have to say I'm a huge fan, Works a lot smoother than Google and Bing too. Also like the customisation you can do with it. Brilliant!

The only query / issue I have is the big lines it draws blue (or themed borders) around countries. See screenshot attached. [image]

I am wondering if there is a method to remove them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with leaflet. The lines are drawn by your tile provider. Change the source of the tiles to fit your needs.

[Cloudmade](http://cloudmade.com/)
[Mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com/)

Comment: Thanks for that @LSA I am using Cloudmade, Although the mapbox maps, Look a lot better.

Comment: @StuBlackett even with cloudmade you can change what kind of map get send.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to take a look at the Cloudmade themes.

Comment: You wouldnt have any idea what property that border falls under would you, In cloudbase that is?

Comment: To those who are wondering.. CloudBases' FAQ's say that the borders cannot be removed. All there style guide does is create a lighter colour of the sea background that you choose.

Comment: @interesting Then I think you'll have to use Mapbox

Comment: @LSA Is it possible to remove these kines in mapbox.Let me know as I can't find a away.