# Edit layers in Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, maps, layer

In **leaflet map**, it shows **Taiwan** as a separate layer from **China**. I want to show Taiwan under China layer, in a web app. How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet JS - Country Boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675274/leaflet-js-country-boundaries)

Comment: See also https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5056